# Proper Request Headers for HMAC

Tags: javascript, http, https, http-headers, hmac

How do I properly send an HMAC with my request to the server? Specifically, I'm not quite sure what to put in my headers. [From Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), it seems as though my headers should contain something in this format

`Authorization: <type> <credentials>`

I believe the `<credentials>` portion is where I place my `MAC` but I am not sure what to put for `<type>`. According to these [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Authentication_schemes), I think I can choose `Basic`. However, I am not entirely sure.

I imagine I can send the request body as is and place the `MAC` somewhere in the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

It's `hmac` for the `<type>`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 